# Django Form Fields Not Displayed

Tags: python, django

Hello i can't make my form work. The button is displayed but the charfield never shows up. I tried to use a if statement with the "sent" parameter and it worked. I just followed the django doc. I did not find a solution in other posts.

Here is my **forms.py**:

```
from django import forms

class CharacterForm(forms.Form):
    character_name = forms.CharField(label='Search', max_length=30)
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import CharacterForm

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'perso/pages/index.html')

def get_character(request):
        character_name = ''
        sent = False
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CharacterForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                character_name = form.cleaned_data['character_name']
                sent = True
        else:
            form = CharacterForm()
        return render(request, 'perso/pages/index.html', {
            'form': form, 
            'character_name': character_name,
            'sent': sent
        })
```

Perso is the name of the app, **Urls.py in perso**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url 

from . import views

app_name = 'perso'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
]
```

**My form in template index of perso**:

```
<form action="{% url "perso:index" %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here is what appears in the browser:

```
<form action="/perso/" method="post">
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='IWmBEknyibHw4LpvjnyfLWKcUOXLbw27RdHgR7GjhTDelCLGZ51QeF3y9wRyC0Mg' />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The charfield is missing. No error in the console.

Comment: what will be `character_name` when your views get a `GET` request. You have anomaly in your code. Check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some anomaly in your code you missed out the template name argument in your render function. Provide the `template name` of your corresponding HTML file in the render function. You also missed providing default arguments of character_name and sent variable. See docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import CharacterForm
def get_character(request):
    character_name = ''
    sent = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CharacterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            character_name = form.cleaned_data['character_name']
            sent = True
    else:
        form = CharacterForm()
    return render(request, 'template_name.html', {
        'form': form, 
        'character_name': character_name,
        'sent': sent
    })
```

You have made mistake to not make `urls.py` pattern for the function in views.py that is setting the form in the template

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from . import views

app_name = 'perso'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^character$', views.get_character, name="character"),
]
```

Also you need correction in your `template` in your post request `URL` link

```
<form action="{% url "perso:character" %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Now your form will be avaliable at http://localhost:8000/character

Comment: Thanks for that! I added the default variables and the template name. The charfield is still not showing.

Comment: here you have! It seems to be dumb but i can't find it out.

Comment: @dcprod Check it out yes you were silly You didn't have any url link to your views function which was sending form

Comment: I'm beginning django, i did not know we had to do it like that. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @dcprod Go through some good source first. It will give you more clear idea and less trouble.